# Python/Pandas filter out unique rows from DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I tow or three DataFrames that have duplicated rows.

```
In [31]: df1
Out[31]: 
    member           time
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00
2       0 2009-10-01 00:00:00
3       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00
4       1 2009-09-30 18:00:00
5       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00
6       3 2009-09-30 12:00:00
...

In [32]: df2
Out[32]: 
    member           time
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00
3       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00
4       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00
5       2 2009-09-30 18:00:00
6       2 2009-10-01 00:00:00
...
```

I'd like to filter out the rows that have unique value of 'member' and 'time' from df1 and df2,  and get a DataFrame that has only rows  that have the common value of 'member' and 'time'  in df1 and df2, that is

```
In [33]: df_duplicated_1_and_2
Out[33]: 
    member           time
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00
3       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00
4       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00
...
```

Is there a efficient and elegant way to do this ?

**Update** If possible, I'd like to get not a new merged DataFrame but a filtered DataFrame. e.g.,

```
In [34]: df1
Out[34]: 
    member           time           value
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00  a
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00  b
2       0 2009-10-01 00:00:00  c
3       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00  d
4       1 2009-09-30 18:00:00  e
5       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00  f
6       3 2009-09-30 12:00:00  g
...

In [35]: df1_filtered_out
Out[35]: 
    member           time           value
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00  a
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00  b
3       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00  d
4       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00  g
...
```

and also get filtered df2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a inner join on `member` and `time` columns:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on=['member', 'time'], how='inner')
   member                time
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00
2       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00
3       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00
```

This will produce a result that has only the rows that have the same `member` and `time` values in both DataFrames.

**Update:**

```
>>> df1.merge(df2[['member', 'time']])
   member                time value
0       0 2009-09-30 12:00:00     a
1       0 2009-09-30 18:00:00     b
2       1 2009-09-30 12:00:00     d
3       2 2009-09-30 12:00:00     f
```

Comment: Merges are 'inner' by default so the `how` parameter is not necessary.

Comment: @EdChum I know, but I explicitly specified the `how` parameter to show the OP how can he change this behavior to `right`, `left` or `outer` if he decides to do a different thing. But yes, this is a useful comment. +1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. Your answer is the almost same as what I'd like to do, but I'd like to get 'filtered' DataFrame, not 'merged'. Could you tell me the way to filter out duplicated raw? (Updated my question)

Comment: @Tetsuro the answer is the same. Just select out the columns from the df2 frame: `df1.merge(df2[['member', 'time']])`

Comment: @Tetsuro Also since this is boolean indexing, you cannot get a view, you will, no meter what you do, get a copy.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez Oh! That's a simple and elegant way! Thank you very much.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez I'd like to get a copy, not a view, so your answer is exactly what I want to do. Thanks for your kind comments.